# Bringing a model or database data into Startup.cs for routes in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Basically I've got a big list of community names that I need to create routes for. Instead of creating a new route for each one :

```
routes.MapRoute(
       "CommunityAirdrieMeadows",
       "airdrie-communities-airdrie-meadows",
       new { controller = "Search", action = "Index", community = "Airdrie Meadows" }
;
```

I'd like to be able to foreach over a list and create them that way. I'm running into the issue where the Startup.cs contains the route configuration in .NET Core. I'm just curious if there's a good way to bring in a list of items that I can use, or if I'm going about this the wrong way.

Comment: You should be able to get a `DbContext` from the service collection if you want to load data from a database in your `Configure` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `IServiceProvider` via `IApplicationBuilder.ApplicationServices`.

E.g.:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        [...]
        builder.UseMvc(routes => MapRoutesFromDb(builder.ApplicationServices, routes));
    }

    private void MapRoutesFromDb(IServiceProvider services, IRouteBuilder routes)
    {
        var communityRepository = services.GetRequiredService<ICommunityRepository>(); 
        var communities = communityRepository.GetAll();
        // Get these from the database.
        var communities = new []
        {
            new
            {
                Name="Airdrie Meadows",
                Template="airdrie-communities-airdrie-meadows"
            }
        };
        foreach (var community in communities)
        {
            routes.MapRoute($"Community {community.Name}", community.Template, new
            {
                controller = "Search",
                action = "Index",
                community = community.Name
            });
        }
    }
```